# calculate the running total over the column contain date difference in HH:MI:SS format in oracle

Tags: oracle, cumulative-sum, date-difference

I have to find the running total over the column interval.

```
SELECT
    ( ( EXTRACT(DAY FROM intrvl) * 24 ) + ( EXTRACT(HOUR FROM intrvl) ) ) ||':'||
    EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM intrvl) ||':'||
    EXTRACT(SECOND FROM intrvl) ||':'|| as interval
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            ( to_timestamp(TO_CHAR(date_column_name,'dd-mon-rrrr hh:mi:ss') ) ) - ( to_timestamp(TO_CHAR(date_column_name,'dd-mon-rrrr hh:mi:ss') ) ) intrvl
        FROM
            dual
    );
```

currrently  Interval column of table has below data:

```
Interval(HH:mi:ss)
0:4:23
696:1:36
696:4:51
8760:1:18
```

Comment: Your problem description is incorrect to begin with; in Oracle, a date difference is a number data type, not an interval. Interval is, indeed, the data type when you take the difference of TIMESTAMPS. Alas, there is no aggregate `SUM()` function for the interval data type (this has been requested as a new feature from Oracle for some time, with very strong support). Now: What do you have as input - a table (or result of query) with a column in interval day to second data type? Does the seconds component have a fractional part? If it does, do you care about it?

Answer (score 4):

The best I can come up with is this. Note that the `interval` data type does not take a format model for **displaying** - you can't force an interval of 25 hours to be displayed as 25:00:00 (although you can use that to INPUT an interval). Instead, it will be shown as 01 01:00:00 (meaning, a day and an hour).

```
with
  tbl (interv) as (
    select interval    '0:4:23' hour(9) to second from dual union all
    select interval  '696:1:36' hour(9) to second from dual union all
    select interval  '696:4:51' hour(9) to second from dual union all
    select interval '8760:1:18' hour(9) to second from dual
  )
select interval '1' day * sum(date '2000-01-01' + interv - date'2000-01-01')
       as sum_interv
from   tbl;

SUM_INTERV          
--------------------
+423 00:12:08.000000
```

In your original attempt you were trying to get a STRING output. I am not sure that's wise, but if that's what you need you can do it like so:

```
with
  tbl (interv) as (
    select interval    '0:4:23' hour(9) to second from dual union all
    select interval  '696:1:36' hour(9) to second from dual union all
    select interval  '696:4:51' hour(9) to second from dual union all
    select interval '8760:1:18' hour(9) to second from dual
  )
, prep (sum_interv) as (
    select interval '1' day * sum(date '2000-01-01' + interv - date'2000-01-01')
    from   tbl
  )
select to_char( extract(day    from sum_interv) * 24
              + extract(hour   from sum_interv), 'fm999999999' ) || ':' ||
       to_char( extract(minute from sum_interv), 'fm00' )        || ':' ||
       to_char( extract(second from sum_interv), 'fm00' ) as sum_interv
from   prep
;

SUM_INTERV        
------------------
10152:12:08
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but i have to find running total not the aggregated sum eg:- first entry in the table is same and the second entry is the sum of current entry with the previous one. and so on..running total is calculated in new column

Comment: @amit - are you familiar with analytic functions? All you need is analytic sum (instead of aggregate). But, for a RUNNING sum, you need an ORDER for the rows; what is the ORDER in the sample you gave? (Hint: obviously it is missing!)

Comment: Yes, I am familiar with the analytic function.. but i am able to perform the running sum for the column has number data type as i got the desired output but if we apply the RUNNING SUM over the column has date interval is getting error that date interval comes in Days to second format.  that acts like string format as per my knowledge.  please correct  if i am wrong.

Comment: @amit - I don't mean "use analytic sum on the interval column" - as you already know that will not work. What I do mean is "**use MY solution from this answer, but change the aggregate SUM into analytic SUM**". I still can't show you how, since you still didn't tell us what is used to **ORDER** the rows though (when you say "RUNNING" sum).